# Assembly Code debugging

Tags: assembly

I have the following assembly code

```
entry: ; initialization
ldi r1, n ; first we load n into a register
ldi r2, 3
ldi r3, 0

rjmp solve

solve: ; solving routine
cpi r1, 0
brmi answer
sub r1, r2
inc r3
rjmp solve

answer:
out PORTD, r3 ; return the answer
rjmp answer
```

Is the error that there is nothing before rjmp solve? I'm guessing that's why it goes in a constant loop

Comment: What _is_ the error? What happens? What should happen?

Comment: What makes you think that there's an error there at all? If you don't know what this code is supposed to do, how do you know it's not doing it?

Comment: Hover your mouse over the downvote arrows. You're getting downvoted because it's not clear what your question is.

Comment: @MikeW I'm thinking the rjmp solve is why it is a constant loop.  Should I add a brmi answer before it?

Comment: @PMF I believe its a simple error because of the rjmp solve...but how do I get out of the loop?  rjmp answer?

Comment: Which assembly exactly is this supposed to be? are you sure it's x86?

Comment: @Leeor its ASM assembly code

Comment: That doesn't say much, I meant which ISA

Comment: Whatever this is, it's not x86 assembler. None of the x86 family have registers called r1, r2, r3, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
cpi r1, 0
brmi answer
```

I guess ri - 0 never gives negative result in 'cpi r1,0'.

Maybe you should try putting 'brmi' after 'sub r1, r2' and
restructure your code a bit to fit. The sub-operation should set the flags
appropriately. Register r1 can't have negative value even if 'sub'-operation can underflow.

This seems to be a rough division by 3 program.